# Xceed datagrid crash

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, xceed

I'm new to Xceed datagrids, and I've been tasked with fixing a bug where the program crashes when there is a duplicate record, and then you click on the 'custom filter' button (dropdown shown):

[image]

The program will crash when there are two date-times that are the same and you click on the little custom filter button on the datagrid. This is the error I get:
[image]

I've tried to locate the function that is called when the dropdown is clicked, but have had no luck. The grid is bound like this:

```
var dataProviderBinding = new Binding
{
    Source = Presenter.OriginalMeasurementRecords,
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
};
dataGridControl.SetBinding(XceedGridWrapper.DataProviderProperty, dataProviderBinding);
```

The format of the data bound seems quite convoluted, so I'll leave it out for now, but I can try to get it if necessary.
Any help is appreciated, and if more information is needed just ask.

Comment: If you reproduce this under the debugger, Visual Studio will break when the exception happens, and should show you the problem code, if it's part of your project. Look at the stack trace either way.

Comment: I have tried this, and Visual studio takes me to one of the starting files (something like App.start), it seems to bubble up to the top and I can't trace it back to anywhere.

Comment: Go to **Debug/Windows/Exception Settings** and click the upper left corner button to toggle VS to break for all exceptions.

Comment: I've done that before and the error still appeared at the 'top' of the program.

Comment: In your `MainWindow` (or `UserControl`), place `InitializeComponent()` within a `try/catch` block, with a breakpoint, and verify if any exceptions are caught this way. Also, always pay attention to your **Output** window in VS.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that ASAP

Comment: One more thing: when VS takes you to some `App.*` file, look for some piece of code containing some exception **e** and hover your mouse over **e**. It should show you in details what exactly the exception is. Here's a [SAMPLE IMAGE](https://imgur.com/a/aatEI) showing it for a UWP app, but you should get something similar in WPF as well.